# Too much of mem table in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have 10 mem tables with each around 1 mb to 50 mb in size,

1) How does the compaction works in this case?
2) What is the difference between Minor and Major compaction and in which frequency these compaction will be triggered by Cassandra

If I have two memtable of 1KB and 1KB under a single partition and during compaction of these two memtables, If a READ comes what will be the workflow, Will be there be a delay in READ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want compaction to consider memtables then you can run "nodetool flush" to flush memtables into sstables.

1. Compaction does not consider memtables while processing.
2. Minor compaction is triggered automatically whenever a new sstable is being created. It does not consider any Memtable. 
   "Major compaction" never happens automatically - it can only be started manually via "nodetool".

Cassandra combine results from the active memtable and multiple SSTables to satisfy a read.

Comment: So you are saying that whenever an mem table is flushed into stable then minor compaction happens? I think this is wrong because as per your case : always there will be only one sstabke for partition. It ends up with no need of compaction

Comment: minor compaction depends on the compaction strategy. STCS, for example, will compact 4 tables of similar size by default. It doesn't happen every time an sstable is written.